# Use of WCF in ASP.NET WebForms C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

What is the use of WCF or what are the advantage having WCF in a ASP.NET Website?

Thank you in advance!

Can you guys simply explain to me before getting a negative opinions to you guys? :) Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. WCF can maintain transaction like COM+ does
2. It can maintain state
3. It can control concurrency
4. It can be hosted on IIS, WAS, self-hosting, Windows services
5. It has AJAX Integration and JSON (Javascript object notation) support

Check out the [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/456672/What-is-the-advantage-using-WCF-over-Webservice-in)

[Here](http://keithelder.net/blog/images/keithelder_net/blog/WindowsLiveWriter/WCFvsASMXWebServices_ABC2/image_thumb_2.png) is a quick look at the WCF:-

[image]

========================================================================

One advantage is you can easily switch protocols and serialization from binary remoting all the way to web protocols. It's also easy to host either in IIS or out.